# opencv2 resize image not working on Mat with user data

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using opencv2. I created 2 `cv::Mat` with external user data (`matLoad` and `matResize`. And resize `matLoad` to `matResize`. However, after the `cv::resize` function is called, the user data is still empty (all `0xCD`). But `matResize.data` is changed and no longer equal to the pointer to the user data. It seems that `cv::resize` resets the destination Mat's `data` property, with a new piece of memory space allocated inside opencv. See below:

```
cv::Mat matLoad(cutw, cuth, cvfmt, mDataLoad);
... // Read image data into `mDataLoad`
cv::Mat matResize(rcutw, rcuth, cvfmt, mDataProc);
printf("%s\n", (matResize.data == mDataProc) ? "equal" : "notequal"); // "equal" is called
cv::resize(matLoad, matResize, cv::Size(rcutw, rcuth));
printf("%s\n", (matResize.data == mDataProc) ? "equal" : "notequal"); // "notequal" is printed
for (int i = 0; i < matResize.elemSize() * matResize.cols * matResize.rows; i++) {
  if (matResize.data[i] != 205) {
    printf("hehe %d\n", matResize.data[i]); // many lines printed, with different values
  }
}
for (int i = 0; i < matResize.elemSize() * matResize.cols * matResize.rows; i++) {
  if (mDataProc[i] != 205) {
    printf("hehe %d\n", mDataProc[i]); // none is printed
  }
}
```

But if I create `matResize` without passing the user data (i.e., let opencv allocate and maintain the memory space by itself), the resize works well.

```
cv::Mat matLoad(cutw, cuth, cvfmt, mDataLoad);
... // Read image data into `mDataLoad`
cv::Mat matResize(rcutw, rcuth, cvfmt);
cv::resize(matLoad, matResize, cv::Size(rcutw, rcuth));
for (int i = 0; i < matResize.elemSize() * matResize.cols * matResize.rows; i++) {
  if (matResize.data[i] != 205) {
    printf("hehe %d\n", matResize.data[i]); // many lines printed, with different values
  }
}
```

What's wrong with the `cv::Mat` created with external user data?

Comment: The `cv::resize` method ignores the initial size and type of the destination image, instead the destination image is initialized based on `dsize` and fx and fy. https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d

Comment: @Zindarod thanks for the reply. But I don't think my problem is about the size and type. My problem is that `cv::resize` seems to reset the `dst` Mat's `data` property, with a new piece of memory space allocated inside opencv. Maybe I didn't describe my question clearly. So I have updated my question. Please help.

Comment: first resize the matrix, then copy its content to `mDataProc`

Comment: @Miki That's a good idea. And I believe it's a common way we use opencv functions. But I need to execute these operations frequently. Frequently allocating and copying memory is too expensive for efficiency. That's why I must use external user data here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dimension of the resized matrix is different from the destination matrix, then the destination matrix will be re-allocated. So to avoid re-allocations you need to be sure that the dimensions agree.

In your code you're setting the destination size as:

```
cv::Mat matResize(rcutw, rcuth, cvfmt, mDataProc);
```

but you're asking for a resized image of size:

```
cv::Size(rcutw, rcuth)
```

You **inverted** rows (height) and columns (width).

So simply create the matrix with the correct size with:

```
 cv::Mat matResize(rcuth, rcutw, cvfmt, mDataProc);
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Oh god. Silly mistake! I forgot that `rows` is ahead of `cols` in the parameter list! Thank you! :-)